# How can I model this in 2D mesh?

Tags: mesh, 2d

*This is my first time ever assignment for a job application using Blender. I have been learning Blender for a month and I should be able to do this on my own, but ...*

I am modeling a cap. It all went well until I got stuck on this little piece. **I have to model it in 2D mesh** and I know it is kinda easy thing to do, but I really couldn't figure out how to proceed it and got stuck here for hours.

I would appriciate all suggestions.
Thank you so much.

[image: New Era Cap Baseball Logo]

Answer (score 2):

Create a plane, select all and bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>), press <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to bevel vertices, press + or - to add or reduce the number of segments, you  can still make some adjustments in the *Operator* box if needed (panel on the bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset, delete the inner face with <kbd>X</kbd> *> Faces*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If this you meant then create a path curve and trace it on the picture.